# Transfer cookies to browser from console c#

Tags: c#, http

I'm sending httpwebrequest to server, and save cookies in environment variable and attach them to requests. I want to know if it is possible to transfer cookies to browser(open some link in browser) and session will preserve.( I authenticate from console, and I want authentication to stay when opening webpage in browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by implementing API on server, which gives id to append to link, to maintain session.